# How to delete an instance of a class within that instance

Tags: c#

```
class Foo
{
    int Data;
    public Foo(int data)
    {
        Data = data;
    }
    public void Diminish()
    {
        this.Data--;
    }
}
Foo Foo1 = new Foo(5);
Foo1.Diminish();
```

Is there Any way delete `Foo1` When Data is `0` within `Foo1`?

(Free up the memory used by that instance)

Comment: What do you mean by "delete"? Free up the memory used by the instance?

Comment: Yes Free Up The Memory @Quantic

Comment: `Foo1 = null;` just set the reference to null, and it will eventually be garbage collected.

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid I don't see any *unmanaged resources* in that class.

Comment: Please see the [Garbage Collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0xy59wtx(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation.

Comment: @user3185569 -- You don't need unmanaged resources to use the IDisposable interface.

Comment: @user3185569 I assume this is a small code demo to show what he want, unless he have a real call named foo doing that

Comment: @user3185569 you don't need unmanaged resources... Use the Dispose method of this interface to explicitly release unmanaged resources in conjunction with the garbage collector. The consumer of an object can call this method when the object is no longer needed.

Comment: @roryap That's what the documentation states: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: going to leave this here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29534/IDisposable-What-Your-Mother-Never-Told-You-About

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An object never decides when to "delete" or garbage collect *itself*. It can't know what else has a reference to it. When there are no references left to an object then it gets garbage collected.

In the scenario described in the question - suppose you had a `List<Foo>()` and then one instance of `Foo` spontaneously decided, based on its own internal logic, that it should no longer exist? I don't know what that would even look like - all references to it suddenly become null?

If that were possible, the defects it would cause would be beyond all mortal comprehension. We have enough trouble when two threads modify the same object or property because of improper/nonexistent locking, and so from the viewpoint of one thread something has changed when it shouldn't.

But this would create similar scenarios even in single-threaded applications.

```
var myFoo = new Foo(1);
myFoo.Diminish();
var x = myFoo.Data; // Null reference exception! WTH - it nullified itself!
```

A fundamental concept of OOP is that classes don't need to know too much about the internal state of other classes. But now you'd need to "know" that a class could suddenly choose to opt-out and jump off the cliff into the GC, and constantly null-check objects that already weren't null.

It's a very good thing that this is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

As some comments and at least one answer explain, a normal reference in a .NET program is exactly what keeps that object alive. It is not possible to "delete" the object explicitly in the way you seem to mean.

An object will remain alive as long as it is "reachable" (i.e. it is possible to start with a "rooted" reference and find the reference to that object). Once it is no longer reachable (which could happen even when a reference to the object exists, as long as that reference can't be reached from a rooted reference…e.g. a circular reference between two objects does *not* prevent garbage collection of those two objects, as long as the only reference to each is from the other).

All of this is discussed in detail in documentation references provided elsewhere.

Now, all that said, depending on what you're actually trying to do, you *might* find that the [`WeakReference<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712738(v=vs.110).aspx) class is what you need. This class provides a way to reference objects without preventing them from being garbage-collected. You can combine this with reference-counting and an object repository to maintain non-weak references to keep the object alive to produce the results you want.

For example:

```
class RefCounted
{
    private static readonly HashSet<RefCounted> _alive = new HashSet<RefCounted>();

    private int _referenceCount;

    public RefCounted()
    {
        AddRef();
    }

    public AddRef()
    {
        if (_referenceCount == 0)
        {
            // the collection ensures a strong reference to the object, to prevent
            // the object from being garbage-collected even if the only other
            // references are weak references.
            _alive.Add(this);
        }
        _referenceCount++;
    }

    public Release()
    {
        if (--_referenceCount)
        {
            // no longer need to force the object to stay alive; if the only remaining
            // references to the object are weak references, then the garbage
            // collector may collect the object.
            _alive.Remove(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
WeakReference<RefCounted> o = new WeakReference<RefCounted>(new RefCounted());
RefCounted r;

if (o.TryGetTarget(out r))
{
    // do stuff with r

    // done with the object? Then call:

    r.Release();
}
```

It is important to note that this is not precisely what you're asking for. The above still does not give you deterministic control over the actual *garbage collection* of the object. Furthermore, once you retrieve the target of the weak reference into e.g. a local variable, you now hold a strong reference to the object for the lifetime of that local variable (i.e. up to the last point that variable is used) and the object cannot be collected during that lifetime, even if the reference count goes to 0 (though at that point the object will of course be collected once that variable no longer exists or is reachable).

But if you really have a scenario where you need to use some type of reference counting to track and in some way control the lifetime of an object, the above is how you'd do it. You would have to store the `WeakReference<T>` objects rather than direct references to `T`, retrieving the target reference at each place in the code where you need it.

Of course, there remains the question of *why* do you think you need reference counting. And even if you need reference counting, why should the reference count be directly related to the lifetime of the object? Your question does not explain these aspects, and so I can't really address them directly. I will say that reference counting is *not* needed at all for effective management of *managed* objects in .NET programs. As long as you don't actively interfere with the maintenance and use of references to managed objects, the .NET garbage collection system will do a far better job of dealing with the lifetimes of objects than you or I could.

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0xy59wtx(v=vs.110).aspx)

> The .NET Framework's garbage collector manages the allocation and release of memory for your application. Each time you create a new object, the common language runtime allocates memory for the object from the managed heap. As long as address space is available in the managed heap, the runtime continues to allocate space for new objects. However, memory is not infinite. Eventually the garbage collector must perform a collection in order to free some memory. The garbage collector's optimizing engine determines the best time to perform a collection, based upon the allocations being made. When the garbage collector performs a collection, it checks for objects in the managed heap that are no longer being used by the application and performs the necessary operations to reclaim their memory.

So the garbage collector will take care of releasing the object when it goes out of scope unless you need to release some expensive (memory consumption) resource. You can sets the reference of the instance to null, this will terminate the object, unless there is some other reference to the object:

```
Foo Foo1 = new Foo(5);
Foo1.Diminish();
if(Foo1.Data == 0)
{
    Foo1 = null;
}
```

Comment: _"You can sets the reference of the instance to null, this will terminate the object"_ -- this is **wrong**. Adding code to set the local variable to `null` _extends_ the lifetime of the object. It is absolutely not the correct way to "terminate the object". (And because of this erroneous advice in the question, it is also wrong to delete this comment -- future readers need to see this, so they are not led astray by the **wrong** advice being provided in this answer).

Answer (score 0):

An object instance will remain "alive" as long as any piece of code references it. So, it's something you cannot really control from within a class.

Answer (score 0):

`C#` is a managed language, you can't "delete" anything, once something can no longer be referenced the value clean up will be handled by the Garbage Collector.

There are edge cases where you need to handle clean up, or be more aware of how you are handling creation:

- Instances of classes that implement `IDisposable` interface should be disposed  of by calling the `Dispose()` method or wrapped in a `using` statement
- Unmanaged resource wrappers, such as `IntPtr` may need to be cleaned up using `Marshal.FreeHGlobal(IntPtr)` or `Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(IntPtr)` if you are required to manage them and you're making a call to unmanaged code
- Static (and possibly long living) values will never be un-referenceable unless you actively set variables to `null` or remove items from collections